# Pasting value into matched cell in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Please help! I've a problem that I've been stuck with for the past day.

I need to transfer data from one sheet to another sheet in another workbook. The output row corresponds to a value in input column a, and output column corresponds to a date in input sheet column B.

I've previously dim-ed the input/out workbooks/sheets as wbin,wbout,sheetin,sheetout respectively. Could anyone help see where my problem is? The error I get is runtime error '9': subscript out of range in the copy destination line.

```
Windows(wbin).Activate
Sheets(sheetin).Select

iMaxRow = 5000
Dim subj1 As String
Dim subj2 As String
For iRow = 1 To iMaxRow

    subj1 = Range("B" & iRow).Text
    subj2 = Range("A" & iRow).Text

    With Workbooks(wbin).Sheets(sheetin).Cells(iRow, 3)
'On Error Resume Next

    .Copy Destination:=Workbooks(wbout).Worksheets(sheetout).Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(subj2 & "*", _
    Workbooks(wbout).Sheets(sheetin).Columns(2), 0) & _
    WorksheetFunction.Match(subj1, Workbooks(wbout).Sheets(sheetin).Rows(2), 0) + 1)
    End With

Next iRow
```

For now, i've disabled the on error resume next. Also, the input column a has 4 numbers followed by string, while the corresponding output row header only has the 4 numbers, hence I tried matching with the wildcard.

Any advice would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way to solve your problem.  You need to use 'Range.Find' instead of 'WorksheetFunction.Match'.

```
Dim dateHeader as Range, foundCell as Range
Set dateHeader = Workbooks(wbout).Worksheets(sheetout).Rows(2)
Set foundCell = dateHeader.Find(subj1)

.Copy Intersect(foundCell.EntireColumn, Workbooks(wbout).Worksheets(sheetout).Rows(subj2))
```

Comment: Hey Seb, Thanks! Could i just clarify, what is foundCell meant to be?

Comment: foundHeader intent to be the cell in Workbooks(wbout).Worksheets(sheetout) that match 'subj1'.  You may have to redefine 'dateHeader' for my code to work

Comment: yeah i did; just changed the row to 2.
I just noticed you included a foundCell as a range, but it wasn't defined. Im just wondering what it does?

Comment: I edited my answer, you should have read :
 Set foundCell = dateHeader.Find(subj1, LookIn:=dateHeader)

Comment: Thanks Seb! It's not quite working just yet but i think I kind of get the idea. Could I ask though, given that my subj2 is "#### texttexttext" and I need to match it to the row in the output sheet with just the "####" on column B, can I use the same method?

Comment: The find method is setted to match the whole content.  You can use :
dateHeader.Find(subj2 & "*", searchformat:=True)

Comment: Could I just check, that would be if the output cell i'm referring to is the longer one right?
Currently my input cell is the one with extra text.
I tried changing subj2 to subj2 = Left(Range("A" & iRow), 4)
and adding Dim idNO As Range, foundRow As Range
Set idNO = Workbooks(wbout).Worksheets(sheetout).Columns(2)
Set foundRow = idNO.Find(subj2, LookIn:=idNO)
and finally
.Copy Intersect(foundCell.EntireColumn, foundRow.EntireRow)

Comment: Yes you got the idea. By the way, remove all the 'lookin:=x' they are a mistake on my part.

Comment: Thanks man!! It doesnt work without the looking:=xs though; not sure why. Right now I'm getting runtime error 1004s with the find, but that's another issue I think. You've been a great help!